# Script running on windows 10 but not on windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell

I have written a script that works great on my machine (Windows 10) but I see an error when I run this code on other machine (Windows 7).

I need the script to check in `c:\users\username\` directory for existence of `tor.exe` or directory called `tor`. The code for this part is this:

```
function FindTor() {
    [int]$answer=0
    $path = "C:\users\$env:username\"

    $torEXE = Get-ChildItem -path $path -recurse -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'  | Where-Object name -eq "Tor.exe"

    $torDIR = Get-ChildItem -path $path -recurse -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'  | Where-Object name -eq "tor"

    if ($torEXE.Exists -or $torDIR.Exists) {$answer = 1}
    Return $answer
}
```

On my computer - no problem. On the machine with windows 7 I get this:
[image: Screen with error]

Comment: the `Where-Object` notation you are using is NEW to ps5 [or perhaps 4?]. if your win7 setup is still on ps2, it just won't work. [*grin*] so you need to go back to using the older scriptblck style.

Comment: Any idea how can it be written so older ps could handle it?

Comment: Take a look at the help and especially the examples!!!  [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7)

Comment: @ShaharWeiss - as `Olaf` mentioned, it is in the help for that cmdlet. [*grin*]